# Any eclipse plugin to find the jdbc connection leakage in java code

Tags: java, jdbc

I have connection leakage problem in my java code. I need to know the eclipse plugin which detects connections/resultset are closed in my java code.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the [findbugs eclipse plugin](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html), it has support for code blocks which [do not close resources](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION).

Comment: Is there a batch tool do same thing?

Comment: You can run findbugs as part of your build process, it will make it slower though so consider running a separate nightly build that runs a variety of static analysis e.g. PMD and SonarQube as well as findbugs